# Compare two CSV files with identical formatting, except mark extreme changes in the numbers day over day

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, export-to-csv

This is my first python project and I am seeking an efficient design to carry out the following task.

I am comparing two CSV's, with no duplicates, Today and T_1. They have pricing for our inventory. 
The CSV's are generated everyday, which will make for a nicer n-1 comparison. The are names in a date convention where todays CSV = 12072015 and t-1 CSV = 12062015.

```
COL(a)-INV ID | COL(b)-PRICE
```

Our prices are constantly changing so I want to implement a tool to essentially do this:

Start on Row 1
Match on INV_ID, if (PRICE[T_1]/PRICE[TODAY])>5% variance, then copy record and dictwrite to a resultant csv.

My inefficient logic is : open both CSV, copy into a third CSV, do difference calculations, delete anything under the threshold of 5% and have a final list. I think this is terribly inefficient yet my mind is only seeing this.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Hunter! My fault on that format mistake.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for ? Is there a problem with your python code ?

Comment: I am at a loss. I have been trying to use DictReader documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params). My process would be open both CSV, copy into a thrid csv, do calculations, delete anything under the threshold of 5% and have a final list. I think this is terribly inefficient yet my mind is only seeing this.-- I should mention this is my first python project.

Comment: Ok you should make that clear. Change your post to add that. You are looking for an efficient design if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I have updated, thanks for your input.

Comment: Can an INV_ID occur more than once in a CSV file?

Comment: This is the beauty, no.They are unique entries. Each ID only has one price.

Comment: @phentrus that should be edited into your answer also

Comment: Is the CSV file changing as this program runs? If not, importing it into a database would make this much easier since you're wanting to do lookups

Comment: As I do not have DB permissions, this is not feasible as it currently stands. I completely agree with you though. Also, thanks for editing my post, I will ensure all future post meet this standard.

Comment: SQLite only requires local file permissions, which you have if you can install and run Python.

Comment: Without explaining it too much, we have our databases which are updated regularly, and real time data feeds. The feeds produce CSV files at certain points. I am at one of those points. You are correct in your logic, there are just barriers on this end.

Comment: So the CSV files themselves do not change, they are just generated at specified intervals?

Comment: And to follow up- this will be run through a workload automation software on our servers, so SQL lite will be a great idea for a desktop tool. The CSV's have a date naming convention. For example today = 12072015.csv and T_1 = 12062015.csv.

Comment: I have modified the original post to include this important detail.

Comment: So should this remain open? It seems the strategy is clear: insert data into sqlite, do comparisons using database.

Comment: That is not a feasible solution in this instance. I need to do this all within SAS and would like a little guidance on the start of this. Thanks for you help thus far though.

Comment: An in-memory SQLite database using the pattern used in the answer given to this question should work fine in that environment. SQLite databases don't have to be written to disk.

Answer (score 2):

I'll chime in with an answer<sup>1</sup> since there are some pitfalls involved with dividing money and this will likely be helpful to a much larger audience than the OP.

It's going to be much easier to work with this data if it's in a database first. This is assuming the CSV file is not changing constantly nor while the Python script is running (by the looks of this, it is likely just a daily report of some kind). You can use a local SQLite database which doesn't require any permissions beyond those needed for creating local files on your machine (if you can install Python on your machine, you can do this just fine).

Assuming data in the CSV file looks like the following (your question gives no sample data):

```
INV ID,PRICE
1,2.60
2,14.88
3,250.65
4,90.10
```

Note that floating point numbers are bad to use with financial transactions since the division will be wrong. Typically developers store prices as integers in SQLite, but for this example I will simply store it as a string since all math will be done in Python using [the `decimal.Decimal()` data type](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html). This is a possible solution (it will obviously need some tweaking for your environment plus some more exception handling and whatnot, but it's a minimal example to accomplish the task):

```
import csv
import datetime
import decimal  # for working with money
import sqlite3


class VarianceTracker():
    def __init__(self, db_path='data.sqlite'):
        # you may need to do some additional work to join/resolve paths to these files if not all local to the folder the script runs from
        self.db_path = db_path  # you could also use an in-memory db only if you don't want to save it
        self.today = self._filename_format(datetime.date.today())
        self.yesterday = self._filename_format(self._yesterday())

        # create table(s)
        self._populate_table(self.today)
        self._populate_table(self.yesterday)  # NOTE: you probably don't want to reinsert data from yesterday if this was done yesterday and still saved in db

    @staticmethod
    def _filename_format(date_obj):
        return date_obj.strftime('%m%d%Y')

    @staticmethod
    def _yesterday():
        return datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1)

    @staticmethod
    def _clean(price):
        # removing commas and extranneous spaces, etc. and storing price as string to avoid floating division errors when expecting decimal math
        return price.replace(',', '').replace('$', '').strip()  # assumes USD $11,244.22 format

    def _populate_table(self, date_name, delim=','):
        csv_file = '{}.csv'.format(date_name)

        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_path) as conn:
            cur = conn.cursor()

            with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=delim)
                for row_num, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):
                    if row_num == 1:
                        cur.execute("""
                            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} (
                              id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                              inv_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                              price TEXT NOT NULL
                            );""".format(date_name)
                    else:
                        sql = 'INSERT INTO {} (inv_id, price) values (?, ?);'.format(date_name)
                        cur.execute(sql, int(row[0]), self._clean(row[1]))

                    conn.commit()

    def _fetch_price(self, table_name, inv_id):
        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_path) as conn:
            cur = conn.cursor()
            sql = 'SELECT price FROM {} WHERE inv_id=?'.format(table_name)
            cur.execute(sql, inv_id)
            return decimal.Decimal(self._clean(cursor.fetchone()[0]))

    @staticmethod
    def _calc_variance(price_yesterday, price_today):
        # be sure to review variance calculation, this is a simple percentage change function
        return ((price_yesterday - price_today) / price_yesterday) * decimal.Decimal(100)

    def find_variances_exceeding_threshold(self, threshold=5):
        # threshold is the variance percentage of interest (5% is expressed 5, not 0.05)
        # writes csv report named {date}_variance_report.csv containing only rows exceeding threshold
        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_path) as conn:
            csv_file = '{}_variance_report.csv'.format(self.today)
            cur = conn.cursor()
            sql = 'SELECT inv_id, price FROM {}'.format(self.today)
            cur.execute(sql)

            with open(csv_file, 'w') as csv_report:
                writer = csv.writer(csv_report)
                writer.writerow(['inv id', 'price', 'variance'])  # write header row

                for row in cur.fetchall():
                    inv_id, price = row
                    price = decimal.Decimal(self._clean(price))  # convert to Decimal()
                    price_yesterday = self._fetch_price(self.yesterday)
                    variance = self._calc_variance(price_yesterday, price)
                    if abs(variance) > threshold:  # use absolute value
                        writer.writerow([inv_id, price, '{0:.2f}'.format(variance)])  # 2 decimal places of variance written


if __name__ == '__main__':
    vt = VarianceTracker()
    vt.find_variances_exceeding_threshold()
```

This could use a lot of improving, but as a minimal example it should give you more than enough (I basically wrote the application for you).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Against my better judgment for a user who has not shown any attempted code and is essentially asking for someone to write code for him/her rather than asking for help with existing code.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for going out a whim on me Bob Dylan. I can assure you that the more I learn, the more I can and will contribute. I wasn't expecting an application written for me, maybe some guidance and such. This is very helpful. Thank you and I hope you didn't get the wrong impression.

Comment: @phentrus this is a programming Q&A site. People generally don't answer questions that don't show a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because it is essentially someone asking for others to write their code for them. People are more so inclined to help someone who has attempted to write an application but can't figure why it doesn't work or want to make it better than someone who has shown zero effort. In this case, however, I am aware of numerous possible pitfalls (doing math with money with floating point operations, lookups in csv files, etc.).

Comment: So I figured I'd help. If the answer is useful to you, please upvote it, and if it solves your problem, mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, I am modifying it to test in my case. I am not 100% it is what I needed but it is a worthy answer that will point me exactly where I needed to be. Thanks.

Comment: And thank you for clearing that up. I would rather people delete my post in this case instead of down-vote me, which only creates a negative learning environment. Thanks.

Comment: @phentrus you probably just need to tweak the SQLite database to be in-memory only and it should work fine for your environment (just change the file name of the db to `':memory:'`). But that's assuming a lot because you did not show any sample data so I had to *assume* what your data looks like.